# Why is it an error such that the x is considered an Object even though it is referencing an array?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, reference, static

Can someone help me understand this piece of code?

```
int[] A = new int[2];
Object x = A; // All references are Objects
A[0] = 0;     // Static type of A is array...
x[1] = 1;   // But static type of x is not an array: ERROR
```

According to the Oracle Java SE site:

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

I understand that arrays can be assigned to `Object` type variables, however, my confusion perhaps lies in the concept of *reference*. When we say `Object x = A`, we are saying that `x` has a reference to the array `A`. However, my confusion lies in `x[1] = 1`. Why is it an error such that the `x` is considered an `Object` even though it is referencing an array? Do I think of `[]` as a kind of method that is only accessible in the "array" class?

Comment: While it is true that an array is an Object, not all Objects are arrays. Hence, the compiler will not allow you to index as if it were an array on the off chance it is one.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between variable type and reference type.  The compiler only knows that  x is an Object, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so do you mean that since `Object x` is not defined as an object, it is considered a variable? Therefore when I define `Object x = A`, this is a variable assignment as opposed to a reference?

Comment: What? Sorry but I can't parse that as your statement above is very confusing and confused. You need to study what a variable is and what a reference is as these are key concepts that you have to know cold. A variable is the thing to the left of the assignment.

Comment: [Language Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html), specifically of note Variables and Objects.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry but I know that anything that's not a primitive type is a reference type, so in the case of `Object x`, `x` is a reference type, correct?

Comment: Yes, `x` is a reference *type*, and it's a *variable*. The only instance or reference in your code above is `new int[2]` which has been assigned to two reference type variables `A` and `x`. Both hold the very same reference or instance, but the *type* of both ***variables*** is different.

Comment: Also, I have absolutely no idea what Thomas Sourtzis is trying to say in his answer or how it relates to your question, but I would advise you to read and believe *anything* that Elliott Frisch has to say as he is one very sharp Java coder.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ohhhh okay I think I understand now! So while they have the same reference, using `[ ]` is only suitable for array types. So should I think of `[ ]` as "methods" since it seems that they only work if the dynamic type is of type array?

Answer (score 1):

While I would not unnecessarily throw away type information, you can use [`Array#setInt(Object, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#setInt-java.lang.Object-int-int-) to access an `int[]` through an `Object`. That is,

```
Array.setInt(x, 1, 1); // x[1] = 1;
```

would work.

Answer (score 1):

`arrays are objects` - This means that array for any type (reference or primitive) are the child class for Object class.

- By using parent reference instance of child class can be accessed. Therefore the statement `Object x = A;` is syntactically correct.
- By using Child reference child related methods/implementations can be accessed. Therefore the statement `A[0] = 0;` is syntactically correct.
- By using parent reference child related methods/implementations cannot be accessed. Hence the statement `x[1] = 1;` is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: So can I think in terms of "Since `x` does not have the static type of array, therefore `x[1] = 1` is incorrect because `[]` only works if the dynamic type is array?"

Comment: I am saying ~x~ is unaware of ~[ ]~ symbol. By using cast conversion or by using java.util.Array methods u can make it array type.